# Ten observations are taken from a normal distribution $X\sim N(0,1).$ What is the probability that (at least) two are within $0.01$ of each other?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, normal-distribution

For each $i\in \{ 1,\ldots, 10\},\  X_i\sim N(0,1);\ $ these random variables are independent. What is the probability that (at least) two of the $X_i$ are within $0.01$ of each other?
And yes, this is equal to $1 - p($ all $ X_i $ are greater than $ 0.01$ apart $),$ but I don't know what to do with this.

If it were two observations rather than ten, you could just consider the distribution of $X_1-X_2.$ But with ten observations this becomes more complicated. Whilst I'm sure there is some convoluted way using combinatorics/inclusion/exclusion and sums, I am more interested in if there is some good approximation or some distribution I don't know about that will help.

Comment: You could consider the distribution of consecutive $n - 1$ differences in order statistics $(X_{(2)} - X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)} - X_{(n - 1)})$.

Comment: I have not heard of "order statistics" before. Interesting.

Comment: They are pretty straightforward: you put the sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ in order from smallest to largest $X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}$. There are general formulas for how they are distributed, both on their own and joint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20kth%20order,non%2Dparametric%20statistics%20and%20inference.

Comment: Simulation will get you an approximate answer quickly: in this case apparently giving a probability just over $0.225$ (last digit not guaranteed)